# Give Friend Post Management

Tags: custom-post-types

On my site you can create a post for someone who is your friend in site.

How do I give permission to my friend to also manage that post as well as me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are an `admin` user, you could just change the author of the post (in the post editor `Author` box) to that of your friend. Admins already have the power to manage anyone's post. By changing the name of the author on the post to that of your friend, you both can manage the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

in wp-admin section->Users->add user(as your friend's detail) and at last there is a field called 'Role'and more about it here: [codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)